# Attempting to use a Json object to define an object's property not working

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, svg

I am attempting to use a Json value to define the fill colour of an SVG circle.

```
        <div *ngFor="let res of moodColours">
          <svg height="50" width="50">
            <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="{{res[0].hex}}" />
          </svg>
          <p>{{res[0].mood}}</p>
        </div>
```

It is defined like this in the page.ts:

```
  setupMoodPalette() {
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Happy", hex: "#fcba03"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Love", hex: "#ff00e6"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Depressed", hex: "#6b03fc"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Anxious", hex: "#eaff00"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Confused", hex: "#807966"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Hurt", hex: "#4c8779"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Angry", hex: "#b51818"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Lonely", hex: "#5a6271"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Guilty", hex: "#F74B02"}]);
    this.moodColours.push([{mood: "Embarassed", hex: "#fc0303"}]);
  }
```

Obviously, my implementation won't work as it cannot be parsed, but is there a way to get it to work in a similar format, or will I need to separate the process of giving it a colour entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using:

```
[attr.fill]=res[0].hex
```

Hope this helps someone else.